# List Bluetooth in Android, works on SDK33 but not on 30

Tags: java, android, sdk

Im trying to list the bluetooth devices on my android app, i have this code that works for SDK 33 phones.but not on a 30 level API, what should i change, to make it work since API 24 to 33??

This the code that runs on API 33 phones

its thing of permissions?? or the broadcast reciever??

This its the main activity, that works on new phones, but it will show blank activity, and no devices on the list if i use a SDK 30 Phone

```
package com.example.bttest;
import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 2;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 3;

    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_LOCATION = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED
    };

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> deviceListAdapter;
    private List<String> deviceList;

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
                String deviceInfo = deviceName + " - " + deviceAddress;
                deviceList.add(deviceInfo);
                deviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.checkPermissions();
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
        deviceListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList);
        listView.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth no es soportado en este dispositivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                checkLocationPermission();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth no está habilitado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
            } else {
                startDiscovery();
            }
        } else {
            startDiscovery();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startDiscovery();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso de ubicación denegado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startDiscovery() {
        deviceList.clear();
        deviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        Log.d("e", "buscando");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Buscando dispositivos Bluetooth...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void checkPermissions(){
        int permission2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
            if (permission2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    PERMISSIONS_LOCATION,
                    1
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And this its the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

\<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"\>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BTTEst"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

\</manifest\>
```

Comment: Try turning ON the GPS/Location.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Please add it to your question if any.